# Accessing a function's local variable outside its scope in Python

Tags: python, scope, reference, local-variables, decoration

Is there a way to access the `memo` variable outside the `memorize` function?
I know that it could be accesses if I would turn it into a function attribute: `memorize.memo`, however I was wondering if there is a way to access it as it is...

Here's the code:

```
def memorize(f):
    memo = {}
    
    def helper(x):
        if x not in memo:
            memo[x] = f(x)
        return memo[x]
    return helper


@memorize
def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
```

Comment: No, you can't access it from outside. You also should not save it in `memorize.memo`, but you might want to save it in `f.memo`, because you want to have a different `memo` for each `f`.

Comment: yes. `global` but usually there are better ways like passing it or just declare it in the module level